# Change in timezones for WRF data using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am extracting from a WRF simulation. The file is a .nc file.
The problem is WRF models in UTC+00. I need it in UTC+10.

Do I need to set the timezone first and then change the timezone?
Or would I change the timezone after I convert to a numpy dataset.

An example of what the timeseries looks like is:
`2018-02-27T00:00:00.000000000`

Many thanks.

```
f=Dataset("wrfout_d03_2018-02-27_00.nc", 'r', format='NETCDF4')
times = wrf.extract_times(f, timeidx=wrf.ALL_TIMES, squeeze=True)

tz_times = pd.Timestamp(times,tz='Australia/Melbourne')
convert_times = wrf.to_np(tz_times)
np_times = np.asarray(local_time, dtype='datetime64[s]')
np_times_ravel = np.ravel(np_times,order='C')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the order really matters.  You just need to remember (maybe with a comment) what you have at each step.  `wrf.extract_times` returns `datetime.datetime` objects in UTC.  `pd.Timestamp` shifts that to UTC+10, but still a `datetime.datetime` (essentially).  The numpy `datetime64` object does not maintain a time zone, but because you've shifted it, the time should be in UTC+10.

If that's what you want, then I think you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

You're totally right, I had to assign UTC to a pd.to_datetime, then I could move onto the local timezone

For all WRF users, adjust your timestamp by:

```
times = wrf.extract_times(f, timeidx=wrf.ALL_TIMES, squeeze=True)
times = pd.to_datetime(times)
times_index = times.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Melbourne')
```

Thanks, Alyce